# SQL exception error message when entering / retrieving from DB

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I attempt to either save data entered from a text box to my DB, or search through data in my DB I am presented with an error message of:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C: \Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Aaron's WPF Project\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I deleted my database, re created it, and re entered the connection string but I'm still presented with this error? Why's this.

Here is my connection string:

```
 SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Aaron's WPF Project\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Comment: There is a space after "C:". Is that also in your code, or a copy mistake?

Comment: Check if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9515685/1592756) has the information you need

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a frustrating hour trying to figure this out. Turns out it's a normal exception thrown inside the .NET SqlClient library, and I could just ignore it and it would continue on and work just fine after that.

Comment: "normal exception" is an oxymoron. No exception should ever be considered "normal".