# con.open has an error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I developed a small project in visual studio 2010. In my project I attach a service-based database named FacturationBD.mdf.

My connectionString is :

```
string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" + @"C: \Users\ANASS\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Facturation_System\Facturation_System\Database\FacturationBD.mdf; Integrated Security=True; Connect Timeout=30";

        byte[] images = null;
        FileStream Stream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader brs = new BinaryReader(Stream);
        images = brs.ReadBytes((int)Stream.Length);

        string position;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Article (Article ID, Image, Réf Article, Désignation, Fournisseur, Quantité, Prix d'achat HT, Prix d'achat TTC,  Prix de vente HT, Prix de vente TTC, TVA) VALUES (@Article ID, @images, @Réf Article, @Désignation, @Quantité, @Prix d'achat HT,@Prix d'achat TTC, @Prix de vente HT, @Prix de vente TTC, @TVA", con))
            {
                string Prix_achat_TTC = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text));
                string Prix_de_vente_TTC = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text) + Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@images", images));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Article ID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Réf Article", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Désignation", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fournisseur", textBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantité", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prix d'achat HT", Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prix d'achat TTC", Convert.ToInt32(Prix_achat_TTC));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prix de vente HT", Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prix de vente TTC", Convert.ToInt32(Prix_de_vente_TTC));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TVA", Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text));
                var name = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (name != null)
                {
                    position = name.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Sauvegarder avec réussite...!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    ClearText();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Non sauvegarder...!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    ClearText();
                }
```

The result:
[image]
[full size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZXNq.png)

Comment: Check this [link]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509441/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-error)

Comment: You have an extra space here: `C:[space]\Users`